# Field \"me\" of type \"User\" must have a selection of subfields

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

Hi I am trying to learn `GraphQL` language. I have below snippet of code.

```
// Welcome to Launchpad!
// Log in to edit and save pads, run queries in GraphiQL on the right.
// Click "Download" above to get a zip with a standalone Node.js server.
// See docs and examples at https://github.com/apollographql/awesome-launchpad

// graphql-tools combines a schema string with resolvers.
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
const typeDefs = `
    type User {
        name: String!
        age: Int!
    }

    type Query {
        me: User
    }
`;

const user = { name: 'Williams', age: 26};

// Provide resolver functions for your schema fields
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    me: (root, args, context) => {
      return user;
    },
  },
};

// Required: Export the GraphQL.js schema object as "schema"
export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

// Optional: Export a function to get context from the request. It accepts two
// parameters - headers (lowercased http headers) and secrets (secrets defined
// in secrets section). It must return an object (or a promise resolving to it).
export function context(headers, secrets) {
  return {
    headers,
    secrets,
  };
};

// Optional: Export a root value to be passed during execution
// export const rootValue = {};

// Optional: Export a root function, that returns root to be passed
// during execution, accepting headers and secrets. It can return a
// promise. rootFunction takes precedence over rootValue.
// export function rootFunction(headers, secrets) {
//   return {
//     headers,
//     secrets,
//   };
// };
```

Request:

```
{
  me
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Field \"me\" of type \"User\" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean \"me { ... }\"?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

[From the docs](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types):

> A GraphQL object type has a name and fields, but at some point those
>   fields have to resolve to some concrete data. That's where the scalar
>   types come in: they represent the leaves of the query.

GraphQL requires that you construct your queries in a way that only returns **concrete data**. Each field has to ultimately resolve to one or more scalars (or enums). That means you cannot just request a field that resolves to a type without also indicating which fields of that type you want to get back.

That's what the error message you received is telling you -- you requested a `User` type, but you didn't tell GraphQL at least one field to get back from that type.

To fix it, just change your request to include `name` like this:

```
{
  me {
    name
  }
}
```

... or `age`. Or both. You cannot, however, request a specific type and expect GraphQL to provide all the fields for it -- you will always have to provide a selection (one or more) of fields for that type.

Comment: Is there a way to do this dynamically?  For example: there is a object of language keys that have translated string values.  But only return the key/value pair that matches the current language key?
eg
```
title: {
  en: "English Title",
  de: "German Title",
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can do that using a combination of variables and the `@skip` or `@include` directive. https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives