# How to fix Error: Type "Extra" was defined more than once in apollo-server, using graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

**Problem**

Hi devs,

I have defined two schemas that technically have the same type, but I get the following error:

`Error: Type "Extra" was defined more than once.`

Is there a way to solve this problem?

My apologies, apollo is new to me and I would really appreciate your help to solve this. Thanks in advance!

**Schema #1**

```
const {gql} = require('apollo-server');


typeDefs = gql `
  extend type Query{
    search(q: String!): [Content!]!
  }

  type Content{
    id: String!
    title: String!
    sinopsis: String!
    poster: String!
    rating: String!
    year: String!
    extra: [Extra!]! 
  }

  type Extra{ 
    channel: String!
    first_air_date: String!
    last_air_date: String!
    total_seasons: String!
    total_episodes: String
    season_list: [SeasonList!]! 
    cast_members: CastMembers!
    similar_series: [SimilarSeries!]!
  }

  type SeasonList{ 
    season: Int 
    episodes: [String]
  }

  type SimilarSeries{ 
    id: String!
    poster: String!
  }

  type CastMembers{ 
    creator: Creator!
    members_list: [MembersList!]!
  }

  type MembersList{ 
    members_info: [MembersInfo!]!
  }

  type MembersInfo{
    characters: Characters!
  }

  type Characters{
    real_name: String!
    character: String!
  }

  type Creator{
    name: String! 
    poster: String!
  }
`

const resolvers ={
  Query:{
    search: async(_source , {q} , { dataSources}) =>{
      return dataSources.API.search(q)
        .then(doc =>{
          return doc.content
        });
    }
  }
}

module.exports ={
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
}
```

**Schema #2**

```
const {gql} = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql `
  extend type Query{
    series(page: Int!): [Series!]!
  }

  type Series{ 
    id: String!
    title: String!
    sinopsis: String!
    poster: String!
    rating: String!
    year: String!
    extra: [Extra!]! 
  }

  type Extra{ 
    channel: String!
    first_air_date: String!
    last_air_date: String!
    total_seasons: String!
    total_episodes: String
    season_list: [SeasonList!]! 
    cast_members: CastMembers!
    similar_series: [SimilarSeries!]!
  }

  type SeasonList{ 
    season: Int 
    episodes: [String]
  }

  type SimilarSeries{ 
    id: String!
    poster: String!
  }

  type CastMembers{ 
    creator: Creator!
    members_list: [MembersList!]!
  }

  type MembersList{ 
    members_info: [MembersInfo!]!
  }

  type MembersInfo{
    characters: Characters!
  }

  type Characters{
    real_name: String!
    character: String!
  }

  type Creator{
    name: String! 
    poster: String!
  }
`;

const resolvers ={
  Query:{
    series: async(_source , {page} , { dataSources }) =>{
      return dataSources.API.getAllSeries(page)
        .then(doc =>{
          return doc.series
        });
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
}
```

**Problem Error**

```sh
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
C:\Users\c\Desktop\cinemanight-graphql\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:234
                throw new Error(errors.map(error => error.message).join('\n\n'));
                ^

Error: Type "Extra" was defined more than once.

Type "SeasonList" was defined more than once.

Type "SimilarSeries" was defined more than once.

Type "CastMembers" was defined more than once.

Type "MembersList" was defined more than once.

Type "MembersInfo" was defined more than once.

Type "Characters" was defined more than once.

Type "Creator" was defined more than once.
    at ApolloServer.initSchema (C:\Users\c\Desktop\cinemanight-graphql\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:234:23)     
    at new ApolloServerBase (C:\Users\c\Desktop\cinemanight-graphql\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:202:30)        
    at new ApolloServer (C:\Users\c\Desktop\cinemanight-graphql\node_modules\apollo-server-express\dist\ApolloServer.js:59:9)
    at new ApolloServer (C:\Users\c\Desktop\cinemanight-graphql\node_modules\apollo-server\dist\index.js:24:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\c\Desktop\cinemanight-graphql\index.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

*Problem corrected using the concept of interfaces and defining types in the same file.*

```
const resolvers = require('./resolvers.js');
const {gql} = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql `
  extend type Query{
    series(page: Int!): [Series!]!
    movies(page: Int!): [Movies!]!
  }

  interface MainContent{
    id: String!
    title: String!
    sinopsis: String!
    poster: String!
    rating: String!
    year: String!
  }

  type Series implements MainContent {
    id: String!
    title: String!
    sinopsis: String!
    poster: String!
    rating: String!
    year: String!
    extra: [SerieExtra!]!
  }

  type Movies implements MainContent{
     id: String!
    title: String!
    sinopsis: String!
    poster: String!
    rating: String!
    year: String!
    extra: [MovieExtra!]!
  }

  type SerieExtra {
    channel: String!
    first_air_date: String!
    last_air_date: String!
    total_seasons: String!
    total_episodes: String
    season_list: [SeasonList!] !
    cast_members: CastMembers!
    similar_series: [SimilarSeries!] !
  }

  type MovieExtra {
    air_date: String!
    country: String!
    runtime: String!
    rated: String!
    cast_members: CastMembers!
    similar_movies: [SimilarMovies!] !
  }

  type SeasonList {
    season: Int
    episodes: [String]
  }

  type SimilarSeries {
    id: String!
    poster: String!
  }

  type SimilarMovies {
    id: String!
    poster: String!
  }

  type CastMembers {
    creator: Creator!
    members_list: [MembersList!] !
  }

  type MembersList {
    members_info: [MembersInfo!] !
  }

  type MembersInfo {
    characters: Characters!
  }

  type Characters {
    real_name: String!
      character: String!
  }

  type Creator {
    name: String!
    poster: String!
  }
`;


module.exports = {
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
}
```